# Chapter number above name and centered - not centering correctly

Tags: luatex, titlesec

Puzzling over this one..

I want something like this: [image]

However with the MWE below I am getting this
[image]

(ignore the variation on font and colour for the moment)

The MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{P548}{RGB}{0,65,86}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\color{P548}\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\newline}{1em}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{My Chapter}
    
    Boom shackalack eget purizzle. Away sizzle amet diam boom shackalack massa we gonna chung pellentesque. Away et erizzle. Vivamus fizzle sapien, lacinia break yo neck, yall, vulputate daahng dawg, condimentum its fo rizzle, nunc. Cras sit shit maurizzle. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{P548}{RGB}{0,65,86}
\usepackage{titlesec,lipsum,emptypage}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries}{\color{P548}\centering{\chaptertitlename \thechapter}}{-2pt}{\color{P548}\Huge\center}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{My Chapter}
    
    Boom shackalack eget purizzle. Away sizzle amet diam boom shackalack massa we gonna chung pellentesque. Away et erizzle. Vivamus fizzle sapien, lacinia break yo neck, yall, vulputate daahng dawg, condimentum its fo rizzle, nunc. Cras sit shit maurizzle. 
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Notice that `\centering` does not take any argument (it is a switch). So the `{}` around `\chapter...` are not needed.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks. I stopped to control because  my output answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `titlesec` is not really compatible with `memoir`.

The problem with your code is `block` instead of `display`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{P548}{RGB}{0,65,86}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\color{P548}\filcenter}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{2ex}
  {}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}

Boom shackalack eget purizzle. Away sizzle amet diam boom
shackalack massa we gonna chung pellentesque. Away et
erizzle. Vivamus fizzle sapien, lacinia break yo neck,
yall, vulputate daahng dawg, condimentum its fo rizzle,
nunc. Cras sit shit maurizzle.

\end{document}
```

Adjust the vertical spacing to suit your needs, but *avoid* using `memoir` and `titlesec` together. There are several tools for redefining chapter styles in `memoir`.

[image]